# CircuitLab circuit icon for drawing schematic diagrams

Tags: discussion

When was the CircuitLab feature (and its icon) added to arduino.stackexchange?

Note, there's an obscurely-titled question, [“How do I describe or draw my circuit in such a way that everybody understands what I am building?”](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12) to which I've added [an answer mentioning the CircuitLab feature](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2393/3917).  I think the feature was added to arduino.stackexchange during October 2016, and would like to know more about it.

Comment: The status-completed tag was added to that question 2016-10-13: http://meta.arduino.stackexchange.com/posts/12/revisions

Comment: Can't believe I missed this myself. Awesome!